# How do you distinguish complements/adjuncts?

Tags: grammar

Is there a reliable test that can distinguish complements from adjuncts?

Comment: If you can say what you think the difference is between them, perhaps some tests can be developed to distinguish them. But you need more than two names and the faith that they're different phenomena.